# How could I add this attribute?

Tags: java

I have a class that is called ShapeBase. It is abstract and draw method must be implemented. It has instance variables for things like width and height. From this, Circle, Line, and Rectangle are subclasses and implement the draw method. The Line class does not have an isFilled property (get / set) but Rectangle, and Circle do. I could obviously just add the property to both separatly, but later on I may want to dynamically gather all shapes that can be 'filled'. I thought of making a filled interface but, the problem is then I have to implement the getter and setter for both. In C++ I'd make use of multiple inheritance to solve this, but what can I do in Java to solve this kind of problem?

Thanks

Comment: I take it a sub-class is out of the question (fillableShape). - I mean for the purposes of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a `FillableShapeBase` which is abstract and extends `ShapeBase` but has the added `isFilled` property with getters and setters. `Rectangle` and `Circle` could inherit from `FillableShapeBase`.

Answer (score 1):

```
public abstract class FillableShape extends Shape {
    // isFilled
}

public class Circle extends FillableShape {
   ....
}

public class Rectangle extends FillableShape {
   ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply make `FilledShape` an abstract class that inherits from `ShapeBase` and implements `isFilled`?